# Why can't I write a formula with VBA?

Tags: string, vba, excel, excel-formula

I've tried to write this Excel formula:

```
 ="Range: ( "&FIXED(MIN('Group2'!$K$10:$K$595);2)&" - "&FIXED(MAX('Group2'!$K$10:$K$595);2)&" )"
```

And it's working perfectly, but when I try to write it with VBA macro, nothing I've been able to find online is working. For example, I've tried with double quotes:

```
Range("D4").formula = "= ""Range: ( "" & FIXED(MIN('Group2'!$K$10:$K$595);2) & "" - "" & FIXED(MAX('Group2'!$K$10:$K$595);2) & "" )"""
```

I would like it so I can change the range passing it as a variable.

Comment: What happens when you look in cell `D4` after running that line of code? What's the issue you're seeing?

Comment: It looks OK to me. The only think I'm wondering about (And I don't know for sure) is if VBA is ok with internationalization. Again, I'm totally not certain that has anything to do with it, but maybe try switching those semicolons over to commas and see if it makes it happy. I'll be surprised if that works, but I feel like it's worth a shot.

Comment: Also. You just say `Range("D4").Formula` but you don't say which sheet. Perhaps this formula is being written out to a sheet you don't expect it to be written to. Instead something like `Sheet1.Range("D4").Formula()`. To @JohnBustos point though, it's not clear if you are getting an error, or the formula being written is incorrect or you just aren't finding it after running the code.

Answer (score 1):

[JNevill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221001/jnevill) you were right the problem was `;` should be a `,`.

The error message I was getting was this:

[image: this].

If anyone needs to use it, passing a variable (named data) would be:

```
Range("D4").Formula = "= ""Range: ( "" & FIXED(MIN(" + data + "),2) & "" - "" & FIXED(MAX(" + data + "),2) & "" )"""
```